# doubt about my last question

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, definition

I have a very basic doubt. If we talk about rooted graph, can we consider any graph whose one vertex is labeled in a special way to distinguished it from other vertices or only rooted tree. this doubt is about my last question [to clear doubt about basic definition in graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462152/to-clear-doubt-about-basic-definition-in-graph-theory).

Here in the definiton can we take any graph like cycles, or complete graphs or only rooted tress. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can indeed consider any graph with one vertex singled out as the root; for more information on rooted graphs you could start [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootedGraph.html). Rooted trees are merely a special case of rooted graphs in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I was very confused. Thanks

Comment: @monalisa: You’re welcome!

Comment: can we start this product after takin |V($G_n$)|=1?

Comment: @monalisa: Are you asking whether we can form the hierarchical product when $G_n$ has only one vertex? Yes, though a factor with only one vertex doesn’t do much.

Comment: yes sir, I am asking the same. I mean $G_n$ wit h only one vertex

Comment: @monalisa: Yes, it’s possible. But if $G_2$ has only one vertex, then $G_2\sqcap G_1$ is isomorphic to $G_1$.